# Setting predefined route name for an app on CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

[Here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#routes) is a documentation on setting routes.

But am still unclear on setting a predefined route to an app

I would like to set the route name as 
`https://my-cool-app-dev-aud.a.b.c.xyz-int.cloud` for an app `my-cool-app`

---

Below is the `manifest.yml` file:

```
applications:
- name: my-cool-app
  instances: 1
  memory: 1G
  random-route: true
  buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
  path: target/my-cool-app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

that is setting the random route.

How to set the predefined route using `route` option? to set route name as `https://my-cool-app-dev.a.b.c.xyz-int.cloud` for app `my-cool-app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `random-route: true` attribute from your manifest.yml.
2. Add a `routes:` block.
3. Under that add a `route: my-cool-app-dev-aud.a.b.c.xyz-int.cloud` route.

That assumes that `a.b.c.xyz-int.cloud` is a domain available to the user that is pushing the application. You may need to add the domain or share it with the user if it is not available.

Ex:

```
applications:
- name: my-cool-app
  instances: 1
  memory: 1G
  buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
  path: target/my-cool-app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
  routes:
   - route: my-cool-app-dev-aud.a.b.c.xyz-int.cloud
```